# Looking for correct kotlinpoet syntax to initialize a PropertySpec.Builder for IntArrays and Array<String> values

Tags: kotlin, kotlinpoet

Don't see the correct syntax for initializing the Array types to the values from an existing types from within the project, primitive types works fine and programmer defined classes

```
Target(
    AnnotationTarget.FIELD,
    AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY_GETTER,
    AnnotationTarget.VALUE_PARAMETER,
    AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY)
    @Retention(AnnotationRetention.SOURCE)
```

annotation class ConfigurableIntArray(
    val key: String,
    val text: String,
    val description: String,
    val initialValue: IntArray
)

```
Class BlockAnnotationTester2(@field:ConfigurableIntArray(
    key = UIComponentSettings.MAXIMUM_LENGTH_KEY,
    text = UIComponentSettings.MAXIMUM_LENGTH_TEXT,
    description = UIComponentSettings.MAXIMUM_LENGTH_DESCRIPTION,
    initialValue = [2]) 
val unusedIntArray: IntArray = intArrayOf(1, 2, 3, 4),

 for (data in memberDataIntArray)...`
addProperty( 
                  PropertySpec.builder(TestAnnotationProcessor.INITIAL_VALUE, IntArray::class) 

                        .initializer("intArrayOf(${data.annotation.initialValue.asList()})")
                        .build()
                ) 
   object Member_BlockAnnotationTester2UnusedIntArray {

    const val KEY: String = 
    "configurable_block_detail_ui_component_maximum_length"

    const val TEXT: String = "Maximum length"

    var INITIAL_VALUE: IntArray = intArrayOf([2]) <-- issue 

const val DESCRIPTION: String = "Maximum length of the corresponding UI 
component"
}
```

Can only get it to initialize to static data in plain text literals or the first value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guessing there is a simpler way but this worked

```kotlin
.initializer("%L", buildCodeBlock {
                                var lregex = 
    data.annotation.initialValue.asList().toString()
                                lregex = lregex.replace("["," ")
                                lregex = lregex.replace("]"," ")
                                add("intArrayOf($lregex)")
                            })
```